Numerical sequence puzzle: 38, 104, ?, 1358
38, 104, ?, 1358
Kudos to anyone who can solve it as it is fairly difficult puzzle.

There could be multiple sequences with these numbers in them.

That's a very short list...any chance of extending it?

No, I can't.  Try to find a pattern

Do they ascend?

@Someone such as? It's unlikely that you will find one with any sort of meaningful "rule" that isn't what OP had in mind.

Well...the interpolating polynomial is a quadratic with integer coefficients so taking $x=2$ gives a perfectly good integer (thinking of the given points as $p(0), p(1)$ and $p(3)$).  Hard to imagine a simpler rule than a quadratic...

Not particularly elegant (ax^2 + bx + c where a = 1188/7, b = -726/7, c = 38), but certainly simple, yes.

38 = 5^2 + 3^2 + 2^2, 104 = 8^2 + 6^2 + 2^2, 1358 = 27^2 + 25^2 + 2^2

maybe the answer is:  496.192307692,
obtained by 1358*38/104, so the ratio between numbers in even positions is the same between numbers in odd positions,
example 1358/104= 496.19.../38;
also the ratio between 104/38 = the ratio between 1358/496.19....
also 1358*496.19.../104= 6479.12... so the ratio between 496.19.../104= 6479.12/1358.
we have the fomrula abab example 104/38, 496.19../104, 1358/496.19..., 6479.12/1358
